# How to make changes istio-ingressgateway when using GKE Istio Addon?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, grpc, kubernetes-ingress, istio, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have google cloud gke cluster installed with istio via addon. I need to change the istio-ingressgateway to NodePort. the problem is that the addon manager is always reverting my changes. Is there a way to disable it from reverting to the original ingressgateway?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make any changes to the istio pods when using the istio on GKE addon. All of the resources in the istio-system namespace are managed and include the label "addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile" which causes any changes you do to be reverted.

The general consensus is that the istio addon is meant more to be a demo, advanced users should install istio manually and use the unamanaged version

Comment: Thanks. I know, but isn't there a way to install addon with EnsureExists instead of reconcile?

Comment: yes, they could do it, but that would have to be modified by the istio team at Google. Your best bet would be to file a feature request through the Google Issue Tracker

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!